# Setting up a JavaScript promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get my head around promises in JavaScript. I feel like I know what a promise is. However, I don't understand how to use them. In an attempt to learn,  I decided to query a database from Node.js. In my code, I have one JavaScript file called test.js. Test.js looks like this:

**Test.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (app) {
  var customerService = require('customer.js')(app);

  var getCustomerTest = function() {
    customerService.getCustomer(1).then(
      function (customer) { console.log(customer); },
      function (error) { console.log(error); }
    );
  };
};
```

**Customer.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(app) {
  var _ = require('lodash');
  var db = require('db');

  return {
    getCustomer: function(customerID) {
      try {
        console.log('querying the database...');
        var database = db.connect(CONNECTION_STRING);
        database.query('select * from customers where [ID]="' + customerID + '", function(error, result, response) {
          if (error) {
            // trigger promise error
          } else {
            // This throws an exception because displayMessage can't be found.
            this.displayMessage('Success');

            // trigger promise success
          }
        });
      } catch (ex) {
        // trigger promise error
      }
    },

    displayMessage: function(message) {
      console.log(new Date() + ' - ' + message);
    }
  };
};
```

I'm struggling trying to setup the promise in getCustomer. Especially since the call to the database call happens asynchronously. I feel like my call to customerService.getCustomer is the correct approach. However, once inside of getCustomer, I have two issues:

1. How do I setup / return my promise?
2. Why can't I call displayMessage after the database query is done? How do I do this?

Thank you JavaScript whiz!

Comment: Look at 2 modules "Q" - https://github.com/kriskowal/q and also, not for promises but for asyncronous callbacks there is "async" - https://github.com/caolan/async.  They both have good documentation and be what you need to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***"Why can't I call displayMessage after the database query is done"***

You are getting the error because `this` is not referencing the object that contains `getCustomer` and `displayMessage`. This is because you are in a callback function and the context has changed.

You need to save a reference to the correct context and use that to access `displayMessage`

```
getCustomer: function(customerID) {
  //saving the context
  var that = this;
  try {
    ...
    database.query('select * from customers where [ID]="' + customerID + '", function(error, result, response) {
        ...
        // Now use it here to call displayMessage
        that.displayMessage('Success');
        ...
      }
    });
  } catch (ex) {
    ...
  }
},
```

***"How do I setup / return my promise?"***

You will need a promise library (unless you plan to make your own). For this I will show the use of the [***q library***](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

There are a couple ways of doing this, but I will show the use of deferreds.

The basic process is:

1. Create a deferred object in a function that will call an async function/method.
2. Return the promise object
3. Set the appropriate callbacks for then/fail/fin etc on the promise object.
4. In the callback of the async function resolve or reject the deferred, passing any arguments that will be needed in the callbacks.
5. The appropriate callbacks that were set in step 2 will then be called in order.

Code

```
var Q = require("q");
...
getCustomer:{
    var deferred = Q.defer(),
        database = db.connect(CONNECTION_STRING);
    database.query("some query", function(error, result, response) {
        if(error){
           //Anything passed will be passed to any fail callbacks
           deferred.reject(error);
        } else {
           //Anything passed will be passed to any success callbacks
           deferred.resolve(response);
        }
    });
    //Return the promise
    return deferred.promise;
}
...

customerService.getCustomer(1).then(function (customer) { 
    console.log(customer); 
}).fail(function (error) { 
    console.log(error); 
}).done();
```

The q library has quite a few helpful api functions. Some help with getting promises with Node async functions. Read the [Adapting Node](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#adapting-node) section of the readme to see how it is done.

[***JSFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/pevans02/fL6Jq/) demonstrating in browser use of q